# Can't init rosdep

Tags: ros-melodic, rosdep

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi there,
I'm trying to install ROS melodic and following: http://wiki.ros.org/melodic/Installation/Ubuntu

after calling:

```
sudo apt install python-rosdep
```

I follow up with:

```
sudo rosdep init
```

and getting:

```
ERROR: default sources list file already exists:
/etc/ros/rosdep/sources.list.d/20-default.list
Please delete if you wish to re-initialize
```

I tried deleting and running init - which then asks me to update and goes back to the error above.

Any help would be great!

Thanks.

Full console log:

```
user@sharon-VirtualBox:~$ sudo rosdep init
ERROR: default sources list file already exists:
    /etc/ros/rosdep/sources.list.d/20-default.list
Please delete if you wish to re-initialize
user@sharon-VirtualBox:~$ sudo rm /etc/ros/rosdep/sources.list.d/20-default.list 
user@sharon-VirtualBox:~$ sudo rosdep init
Wrote /etc/ros/rosdep/sources.list.d/20-default.list
Recommended: please run
    rosdep update
user@sharon-VirtualBox:~$ rosdep update
reading in sources list data from /etc/ros/rosdep/sources.list.d
Hit https://raw.githubusercontent.com/ros/rosdistro/master/rosdep/osx-homebrew.yaml
Hit https://raw.githubusercontent.com/ros/rosdistro/master/rosdep/base.yaml
Hit https://raw.githubusercontent.com/ros/rosdistro/master/rosdep/python.yaml
Hit https://raw.githubusercontent.com/ros/rosdistro/master/rosdep/ruby.yaml
Hit https://raw.githubusercontent.com/ros/rosdistro/master/releases/fuerte.yaml
Query rosdistro index https://raw.githubusercontent.com/ros/rosdistro/master/index-v4.yaml
Skip end-of-life distro "ardent"
Skip end-of-life distro "bouncy"
Skip end-of-life distro "crystal"
Skip end-of-life distro "dashing"
Skip end-of-life distro "eloquent"
Add distro "foxy"
Add distro "galactic"
Skip end-of-life distro "groovy"
Add distro "humble"
Skip end-of-life distro "hydro"
Skip end-of-life distro "indigo"
Skip end-of-life distro "jade"
Skip end-of-life distro "kinetic"
Skip end-of-life distro "lunar"
Add distro "melodic"
Add distro "noetic"
Add distro "rolling"
updated cache in /home/user/.ros/rosdep/sources.cache
user@sharon-VirtualBox:~$ sudo rosdep init
ERROR: default sources list file already exists:
    /etc/ros/rosdep/sources.list.d/20-default.list
Please delete if you wish to re-initialize
user@sharon-VirtualBox:~$
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/401167/can%27t-init-rosdep/) by [AibohphobiA](https://answers.ros.org/users/57608/aibohphobia/) on ROS Answers with karma: 87 on 2022-05-23

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

`rosdep update` is a different sub command and is not saying that you should rerun the init,`rosdep init`. If that's not clear to you. Please include the full console outputs of your commands that you're running including the commands your running and the full outputs of those commands so that we can reproduce the issue.

---

Originally posted by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) with karma: 58457 on 2022-05-23

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [AibohphobiA](https://answers.ros.org/users/57608/aibohphobia/) on 2022-05-24**:
Hi & thanks for the quick reply! I added the full console log to my original post.
Maybe I didn't describe the problem properly, but you can see from the log that I just can't call rosdep init. Dun't know why :(

**Comment by [Joe28965](https://answers.ros.org/users/50769/joe28965/) on 2022-05-24**:
That's because you need to call `rosdep init` once. And I mean once per installation. After you've run `rosdep init` you never have to run it again. You do have to run `rosdep update` from time to time, but you never have to initialize it again.

Which is what the error means:

```
ERROR: default sources list file already exists:
    /etc/ros/rosdep/sources.list.d/20-default.list
Please delete if you wish to re-initialize
```

`default sources list file already exists` means that it already has *created* the sources list. Then when you run `rosdep init` after removing the file, it gives you the following result:

```
Wrote /etc/ros/rosdep/sources.list.d/20-default.list
Recommended: please run
    rosdep update
```

In other words, it has created the sources list and recommends you to update it. After that you never have to run `rosdep init` again.

**Comment by [AibohphobiA](https://answers.ros.org/users/57608/aibohphobia/) on 2022-05-24**:
Oh wow, silly me. just waster a lot of time on nothing.
Thanks for your help! btw, is there any was of testing that it's initialized and working properly?

**Comment by [Joe28965](https://answers.ros.org/users/50769/joe28965/) on 2022-05-24**:
If `rosdep update` works as it does in your case (going through the distro's and ending with `updated cache in...`) you know it is working properly.

Also, please accept tfoote's answer to move this question to indicate that this question is answered.

**Comment by [AibohphobiA](https://answers.ros.org/users/57608/aibohphobia/) on 2022-05-24**:
Thanks for your help!